# render custom attributes on HTML elements with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, node-webkit

Is there a way to make reactjs render custom attributes on an HTML element?
I am developing this app with node webkit using react, and i need to add webkitdirectory and mozdirectory attributes to an file type input element to be able to select directories.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Custom HTML Attributes** from [JSX Gotchas](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html#custom-html-attributes).

> If you pass properties to native HTML elements that do not exist in the HTML specification, React will not render them. If you want to use a custom attribute, you should prefix it with data-.

If it's essential that you use an attribute that isn't prefixed with `data-`, you'll have to add it yourself using the DOM API inside your component.

```
giveCustomAttributes: function(input) {
  input.setAttribute('webkit-directory', '');
  input.setAttribute('moz-directory', '');
},
render: function() {
  return (
    <input type='file' ref={giveCustomAttributes} />
  );
}
```

If you want a more declarative approach you could move this behaviour into a mixin, in order to share it between components.

```
function CustomAttrsMixin(refName, attrs) {
  return {
    componentDidMount: function() {
      var attrNames = Object.keys(attrs),
          element = this.refs[refName];

      attrNames.forEach(function(attrName) {
        element.setAttribute(attrName, attrs[attrName]);
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Then call the function with the appropriate values to create the mixin itself.

```
mixins: [CustomAttrsMixin('input', {
  'webkit-directory': '',
  'moz-directory': ''
})],
render: function() {
  return (
    <input type='file' ref='input' />
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks, there is a small bug in the code you provided though as setAttribute should be called on the DOM node and not on the ref object.
var input = this.refs.input.getDOMNode();

then i hook componentWillReceiveProps to unset the attributes should i need to. problem solved!

Comment: Not used `refs` in a while. Can't see anything about `getDOMNode` in the docs, but I'm sure you're right. Apparently, using the string attribute is [pretty much legacy support now](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute), so I updated the answer with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

mixins is not supported in ES6 of ReactJS.

I use this code

```
componentDidMount(){
  var input = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.customAttributes)
  input.setAttribute('webkitdirectory', '')
  input.setAttribute('directory', '')
  input.setAttribute('multiple', '')
}
```

and

```
<input type='file' ref='customAttributes'/>
```

to upload a whole folder